# Q: svg.js panzoom to fit window

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm having issues when exporting my SVG to PNG using svg.js and saveSvgAsPng.

The issue seems to be that saveSvgAsPng saves whatever portion of the SVG content that is shown to the user instead of the entire SVG file.

So; my question is how do I pan/zoom programatically so that my SVG content fills the entire view of the browser?

I already use the panzoom plugin for svg.js but there is no solution here either.

Comment: You want to set the viewbox manually for that. Make the svg 100% of the browsers width and height and set the viewbox so that it encloses the area you want to save.

Comment: The viewbox is set as follows:

SVG_CANVAS = SVG('svg').size('100%','95%');

My issue is to zoom/pan to make the content fill the whole viewbox.

Comment: After some googling I fixed it:

`function zoom_to_fit() {
   var bbx = calc_bbox();
   var vp = SVG_CANVAS.viewbox();

   var s = Math.max(bbx.width/vp.width,bbx.height/vp.height);

        var box = new SVG.Box(SVG_CANVAS.viewbox()).transform(
          new SVG.Matrix()
            .scale(s,s)
            .translate(-vp.x,-vp.y)
        );

        SVG_CANVAS.viewbox(box); 
  }`

Comment: can you pls post this comment as answer? Even when you answered your own question you can post it here so people can easily see that this question has an answer